# ui-sref not working approperly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have a very basic angularjs app, using `ui-router`. The `stateProvider` is defined as follows:

```
$stateProvider
  .state 'home',
      url: '/'

  .state 'products',
      abstract: true
      url: '/products'
      templateUrl: 'partials/products/products.html'

      resolve: {

        productsResource: 'Product'

        data: (productsResource) ->
          return productsResource.all().$promise
      }

      controller: ($scope, data) ->
        $scope.products = data.products
        $scope.pagination = data.pagination

    .state 'products.list',
      url: '/page/{pageNum:[0-9]{1,4}}'
      templateUrl: 'partials/products/products.list.html'


    .state 'products.detail',
      url: '/{productId:[0-9]{1,10}}'
      templateUrl: 'partials/products/detail.html'
```

This is `coffescript`, since the backend is in `rails`.

The `home` state is loading correctly, there I have the following piece of code:

```
<h2>Products</h2>

<a ui-sref="products.list({pageNum: 1})" class="btn btn-primary">See All</a>
```

And the `products.list` state loads correctly. The problems is when I try to reach the state `products.details`

```
(inside products.list.html)

<a class="btn btn-xs" ui-sref="products.detail({ productId:product.id })"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Detail </a>
```

The link generated by `ui-sref` seems correct: `href=/products/3621`, but it asks for the file in: `http://localhost:3000/products/page/partials/products/detail.html`, and I do not understand this behaviour.

Why is happening this? How can I fix it?

(I am using `angular 1.3`, and `ui-router 0.2.10`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it looks up the template by relative url. You don't have '#' in your urls, aren't you?

Try defining absolute urls to templates, like `templateUrl: '/partials/products/detail.html'`

Comment: I didn't have `#` in my urls, but I have mixed absolute and partials urls, that was the problem... (duh) Thanks @gorpacrate